# Can I add this xsl:if test into the xsl:for-each test?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Here is a snippet from a XSL script:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name">
    <xsl:sort select="@Counsel" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:sort select="local-name(../../..)"/>
    
    <xsl:if test=".=$strName and @Counsel">
        <tr>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Counsel"/>
            </td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black">
                <xsl:variable name="strWeek" select="local-name(../../..)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 8, 2)"/>
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 5, 2)"/>
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($strWeek, 2, 4)"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I modify the `for-each` selection path to include the `xsl:if` clause? So:

1. `$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name`
2. `Name=$strName`
3. Has `@Counsel` attribute

Then I can remove the inner `xsl:if` clause because the `xsl:for-each` selection path is already doing it.

I tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[$strName and @Counsel]">
```

### Doesn't work.

This bit now works:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel]">
```

But when I try to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel]=$strName">
```

Fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HistDB//AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item/Name[@Counsel and .=$strName]">
```

Untested, because you did not provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Worked a charm. I have another question based on this same `for-each` loop but that is best asked separately.